# Execute Remote Process As DOMAIN/User Interactivly

Tags: .net, wmi

Using .NET, I have a requirement in which I need to execute a process (a console app) on a remote PC within my domain. The process needs to be opened interactively (can be seen from the remote desktop) and be executed as a specified domain account.

My .NET application runs as a Windows service and its execution account has admin on both boxes. The user account I need to open the process is a different account than the service but also has admin on the remote client (which is unfortunately, Windows Server 2000).

Comment: Is your service running on the other PC? If not, you'll need to look into remote WMI.

Comment: No, the service is running on a separate server than the server in which I want to start the process interactively.

Comment: Then all the usual stuff about CreateProcessAsUser doesn't apply, since you don't have any code running over there. You'll need to use WMI.

Comment: The WMI function Win32_Process.Create() looked promising, but I cannot determine if it can be used to start the process interactively so that the specified user will see the process' window on their desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to go ahead and close this as not possible; I will try to get my requirements changed so that my service will run as the same user I need to execute the process as or to run the service/script locally.

Thanks for the replies,
Zach Skinner

Answer (score 1):

See this: [How to execute program on remote computer?](http://motevich.blogspot.com/2007/11/execute-program-on-remote-computer.html)

It uses the `Win32_ScheduledJob` WMI class to execute a process that can be seen on the interactive desktop of the remote computer.

Comment: Thanks for the link; this may be what I was looking for. Unfortunately, I am having difficulty in finding a way to query the remote server's time so i can schedule ASAP. `Win32_LocalTime` is not available for Win Server 2000.

Comment: Once you test it I believe you will find it is interactive only if the target user is logged in.

Comment: The question's not clear: is the logged-in user (if any) the user as whom to run the process? If they're the same, this'll work. If not (as you say) it won't.

Answer (score 0):

There is no *supported* way to create a token that will function as a specific user and display on a specific desktop.

If you do not need to access any network resources, NtCreateToken can construct an arbitrary token. To find the nonce SID you need to combine with the login SID, steal the winlogon token for that session.

If you can function as SYSTEM instead, steal the winlogon token and use it directly.

EDIT: since this is a console app, you can probably arrange to do something like open a telnet-like process (steal winlogon token) and connect it via socket or named pipe to your worker (no window).